# Check if $ f(A \cap f^{-1}(B)) $ is a subset of $f(A) \cap B $.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f : X \rightarrow Y , A \subset X, B\subset Y $

Check if $ f(A \cap f^{-1}(B)) $ is a subset of $f(A) \cap B $.

$f(A) = \{y: \forall x \in A \ y=f(x)  \}$ Edit: this is incorrect!

$f^{-1}(B) = \{x: f(x) = B \}$

$f(A \cap f^{-1}(B)) = \\\{y: \forall x \in (A \cap f^{-1}(B)) \ y=f(x)\} = \\\{y: \forall x \in A \land \forall x\in f^{-1}(B) \  y=f(x)\} =\\ \{y: \forall x \in A \land \forall x\in f(x)=B \  y=f(x)\} = ? $

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Your statements $f(A)=\ldots$ and $f^{-1}(B) = \ldots$ are wrong.

Comment: @Student: $f(A)=\{f(x)\::\:x\in A\}$ and $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\::\:f(x)\in B\}$

Comment: Oh the book I was using had some other quantifier notation and made a mistake reading which was which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$ and $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in B\}$.

The last definition states that $x\in f^{-1}(B)\iff f(x)\in B$.

We can conclude directly that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$.

Now observe that:

- $A\cap f^{-1}(B)\subseteq A$ so that $f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f(A)$
- $A\cap f^{-1}(B)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$ so that $f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f(f^{-1}(B)\subseteq B$

Then consequently: $$f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f(A)\cap B$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a subset of $f(A)$ (why?).  It is a subset of $B$ (why?).  Therefore ...

Comment: Wow very good answer